# Inclusion of a JSON object between two seperate JSON files

Tags: json

I have an object definition in `common.json` file that I need to use in number of other JSON files in terms of reusability. Is there any way to include my `common.json` file into other JSON files?

**Edit:**
I came across [JSON Pointer](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6901) while searching which made me thought JSON alone can handle it. To be more clear:
***common.json***

```
{
  "common": 
  {
    "course": 
    {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": 
      {
        "course_name":  { "type": "string" },
        "course_id":    { "type": "integer" },
        "course_room":  { "type": "integer" }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

***other.json***

```
{
  "weekly_schedule": 
  {
    "mathematics":  { "$ref": "common.json#/course" },
    "history":      { "$ref": "common.json#/course" }
  }
}
```

What I understand from here is I can refer to a common JSON object from elsewhere using its path and the `$ref` keyword. Is that correct or am I missing some point?

Comment: [JSON](http://json.org) is text representation of some data structure (usually an array or object). In order to use it, it has to be decoded back into data structures similar to those used to create it. The data structures can be then manipulated as needed.

Comment: @axiac Thanks. I found something called JSON Pointer and edited my post. I didn't quite understand how that works. Do you have any idea about it?

Answer (score 1):

JSON is a very simple metaformat. If you take a look at its specification, you will find how simple it is. In particular, it doesn't define any means of aggregation, namespaces, schemata like they are available in XML.

If you want to manipulate JSON or compose different JSON-files, you either treat them as a whole (i.e. as text) and then apply text tools or you decode them, manipulate the received data and then encode the results again.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Although the common opinion is JSON is a simple format and can't handle advanced functions as XML does, I just read about [JSON Pointer](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6901) which made me think again. Still I can't say I quite understood its structure. Do you know how that works?

Answer (score 0):

No, JSON is just text. It doesn't do anything on it's own.